# How to send array of structs using Foundry cast

Tags: solidity, blockchain, arrays, struct, foundry

Smart contract

```
    struct NewPrice{
        address asset;
        uint256 timestamp;
        uint256 price;
    }

    function updatePrices(NewPrice[] memory _array) public onlyRole(FEEDER_ROLE) {
        for(uint256 i=0; i<_array.length; i++){
            address asset = _array[i].asset;
            uint256 timestamp = _array[i].timestamp;
            uint256 price = _array[i].price;
            putPrice(asset, timestamp, price);
        }
    }
```

cast

```
cast send CONTRACT_ADDRESS "updatePrices((address,uint256,uint256)[])" "[[ADDRESS,2000,2000],[ADDRESS,3000,3000]]" --rpc-url URL --private-key=PK
```

result

```
Error:
Failed to parse tokens

Context:
- Invalid data
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Figured it out!

```
cast send CONTRACT_ADDRESS "updatePrices((address,uint256,uint256)[])" "[(ADDR,100,200),(ADDR,300,400)]" --rpc-url RPC_URL --private-key=P_KEY
```